# Argparse allow mutually exclusive group argument's argument in any position?

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, argparse

I have an usage with `argparse` that current looks like this:

`[-h] (-m USE_MAKEFILE | -e USE_EXECUTABLE) [-v]`

And it all works fine, but the argument that `-m` and `-e` use HAVE to be proceed right after. Thus, if I run the program like this: `main.py -mv Makefile`, it will not work because it did not get the argument it was expecting. It will only work when I do `main.py -vm Makefile` because the Makefile proceeds after the `-m` option, it works.

Is there anyway I can have the `Makefile` be the last argument, while still specifying `-m` or `-e` in any order?

Here is the code I currently have:

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Simple Auto Tester")
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument("-m", "--use-makefile", action="store", help="Use Makefile to run tests")
    group.add_argument("-e", "--use-executable", action="store", help="Use Executable to run tests")
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", action="store_true", help="Verbose logging")
    return parser.parse_args()
```

Also, another hacky solution I discovered is this:

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Simple Auto Tester")
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument("-m", "--use-makefile", action="store_true", help="Use Makefile to run tests")
    group.add_argument("-e", "--use-executable", action="store_true", help="Use Executable to run tests")
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", action="store_true", help="Verbose logging")
    parser.add_argument("file", metavar="Makefile or executable", type=str)
```

Is there any other solution to this besides using the positional argument?

Comment: I actually like the "hacky" solution. It's clearer, to the point, and... works. It will be better than any other, actually hacky solution that will probably have to manually mingle the arguments after `parse_args` is called.

Comment: Oh, okay then. First time using argparse, so I am just getting a feel for it. Thank you!

Comment: Allowing `-vm file` is just a short cut for `-v -m file`. If `-m` takes a value ('store'), the value has to follow the flag.  Use the pattern that makes most sense to your user (or you 6 months hence)